# Remapping keys to match Windows

Tags: keyboard

I'm completely new to the Mac and I have a whole lot of problems with the shortcuts etc.

Is it possible to remap the keys to match my windows expirience? For example I'd like to have CTRL+C, CTRL+V as Copy & Paste.

Comment: You really should learn the Mac way of doing shortcuts (the Command key). After a few weeks of using both platforms, your brain will learn to use Command on the Mac and Control on Windows without you having to think about it.

Comment: That's not an option. I need it remapped.

Comment: Why is is not an option?

Comment: @Cajunluke Because that is what he wants, just as I want the same.

Comment: Guys you can argue day and night but basic shortcuts at Mac are stupid, like deleting file you have to use Command+Delete, huh who does that, if there is key with name "delete" then using command with that what kind of logic is that,, same goes with Command+Enter. This is stupid and completely insane. Just moved from Windows and now I see that Windows is Democracy and Mac is Communism.

Comment: Please keep comments restricted to answering the question. Arguing about which is better, or why they are asking, is irrelevant and rude.

Comment: "You really should learn the Mac way" :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What I recommend for you is remapping the keys so that pressing the Control button on your keyboard tells you computer that you're pressing command. That way, you can use the button you're used to automatically without having to set up each shortcut you want. Here's how:

Go to System Preferences (in your Applications folder) and click `Keyboard`. Go to the `Keyboard` tab and click the `Modifier Keys...` button.

Select your keyboard from the `Select keyboard...` menu.

To give yourself a Windows-like experience, do the following:

In the first menu, Leave `Caps Lock` alone.

Set the second menu to `Command` so that the line reads like this: `Control (^) Key: ⌘ Command`

Change the third menu to `Option`.

Change the fourth menu to `Control`.

With this setup, pressing the `Contro`l button will make the computer think you've pressed `Command`. So, any shortcut that says `command-v` will work when you press `control-v`. The option key behaves like the alt key. The command button works as the control key usually does on a Mac. You can use it for things such as right-clicking.

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I found was [the free KeyRemap4MacBook utility](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) -- it lets you change the keyboard in many ways. My personal modifications (for the MacBook Air 2012 model):

- "fn + cursor left/right" for Home/End and "fn + up/down" for PgUp/PgDown, via *For PC Users*: *Use PC Style Home/End*, *Use PC Style PageUp/PageDown*
- switching the function keys to work like on "PC" notebooks, i.e. F1-F12 without modifier and "fn + Fx" for the screen brightness etc changes, via *Functional Keys to F1..F12* plus *Fn+F1..F12 to Functional Keys*.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Karabiner Elements, a more complete tool for remapping keys

Answer (score 0):

go to system preferences --> Keyboard --> Keyboard Shortcut from left windows choose Application Shortcut and in the below of right window press + button and in Application choose All application and in menu title choose `Copy` and in keyboard shortcut press `ctrl+c` and do the same thing for paste shortcut.

Comment: This will certainly work, but it's less than ideal to have to reconfigure every shortcut, especially since not all apps obey SysPrefs-configured shortcuts.

Comment: Didn't work for me :(