# PC-like keyboard emulation on Mac OS X 10.6.3

Tags: mac, keyboard

I got myself a Mac Mini and started using it with a PC keyboard as I don't have the time to learn Apple keyboard shortcuts at the moment.

I was wondering if there is some kind of keyboard emulator that will make <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>, and <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> work as they do in Windows.

Comment: Slightly related, FYI: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10471/remapping-keys-to-match-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is "no".  Each application is going to have its own set of keystrokes to perform certain actions, and most of those are built around the OSX standard way of doing things.  For example, in Firefox Command+1 will always be the option for the first tab, even if you find some way of doing what you want.  Command+Tab will not cycle through individual windows, only applications, etc.

You can try some of the "shortcuts" listed in [this similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10471/remapping-keys-to-match-windows), or [this similar answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183/mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcuts#answer-196), but this is basically adding training wheels, and is not likely to work with every application.

For the long run, your best bet is to ditch the PC keyboard (not that it makes any difference, except what logo is on the Command key) and start learning.  After a week or two of using OSX every day, you'll probably find that your level of comfort with your new OS has skyrocketed, and you're using command+v to paste without thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jack M I agree that you should try to learn the more common apple shortcuts. But for special cases try [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/). Besides PC-style remapping you can have emacs- and vi-mode and any other remapping you can and can't think of.

Check out the all the possible keybindings here.
http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a great program that enables this functionality in OSX called "[Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/)". It used to be free but is now costs money ($6 I think). This let's you easily create system-wide or software-specific key bindings. It also enables MS Windows like window snapping, where you can drag a window to the side of the screen to have the window take up half of the monitor, etc.