# How to make my 124-key keyboard work under OSX as it does in Windows

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm a long-term Windows user recently welcomed into the Apple universe through work.
My typing muscle memory is pretty much baked in.
Things like control-delete, control-insert, numberpad enter and, of course, the "right click/open submenu" key are things i use all the time unthinkingly.
And the navigation keys like home/end and page up/page down, along with their chord extensions.
OSX is pretty configurable and karabiner is insanely powerful.
I can't believe this isn't something that someone smarter and more motivated than me has done before.
Does anyone have an OSX/karabiner config that I could use?

ETA: i've been coddled for a while since I use a windows emulator for which the keys all work fine. (Except, oddly, numberpad enter.) now, though, i've started coding in VS for Mac and it's really rather frustrating.

Comment: This particular question is asked all the time; here’s just [one example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/10492/119271). The best advise is to aclimate yourself to the new shortcuts because apps expect these shortcuts, not Windows ones and remapping them in this manner can cause unintended consequences.

Comment: https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=%20PC-Style%20Shortcuts

Comment: thanks, allan. you say "apps expect these shortcuts, not Windows ones." isn't the whole point that the bits sent by the keyboard need to be interpreted by the OS? and that windows keystrokes have a meaning, and that meaning is represented by a different set of keystrokes on the mac? surely all that is required is for the transparent substitution of one into the other. when i press the end key on my keyboard i don't care what keystrokes are sent, just that it moves the cursor to the end of the line, instead of scrolling to the end of the document without moving the cursor.

Comment: thinking about it, i understand that emulating F5, say, is an impossible task. its interpretation is very much app-specific, and its functions would be represented by different keystrokes, even within the same app. things like control-insert, though, unless overridden by the developer, always do one and only one thing. for control-insert, this is "cut". the same with home and page up. straight one-to-one mappings like this can't be that hard.

Comment: App developers write code expecting these standardizations.  They then can use un-mapped bindings for their app.  If you remap things en-masse like  this you can potentially conflict with app mappings.

Comment: exactly so. which is, perhaps, the source of my frustration. i'm using visual studio. the developers have mapped ctrl-x and -v and ctrl-left and -right. they've also mapped home and end and ctrl-home and ctrl-end. they've missed ctrl-insert and ctrl-delete, though, which are the ones i use the most. and since just before i use them i'm holding down shift with my left hand and have just pressed home or end with my right, i'm more than ready.